# Perl regex output hyphens multiple "words"

Tags: regex, perl

When I have a string with multiple hyphens in it, I seem to be able to find the (only) desired value, but why are there multiple outputs?  I'd like to just report the matched string entirely, with hyphens.  I've included what the output probably is, along with a way to rebuild the string, but this method seems like unnecessary work.

```
my $string = "phonenumber123-456-7890";
my @secondStrings = $string =~ m/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g;
foreach (@secondStrings){
    print $_, "\n";
}
if ($string =~ m/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/g){
    print $1."-".$2."-".$3, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why you don't put all in a single capturing group?

Comment: Why the down votes on this question. The issue may be obvious, but to someone with a lack of experience using Perl / regexps, specifically capture groups, it won't. If its because of the wording of the question, that might inadvertently be as a direct result of this lack of understanding.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just want to put the entire phone number (123-456-7890) into 1 capture group, right now you are using 3.

```
my ($number) = $string =~ m/(\d+-\d+-\d+)/g;
```

Further reading can be found here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups

Comment: I believe you meant `my ($number) = $string =~ m/(\d+-\d+-\d+)/g;` otherwise $number in scalar context will be assigned the number of elements captured.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  This is solved for all practical purposes, but if there is only one match, why would I need a capturing group anyway?